# URLSessionDownloadTask - Fails without an apparent error

Tags: swift, macos, nsurlsession

[I just made a class](https://gist.github.com/pixelomer/3b7a638222942a356be3a830662aea27) to download files easily in the background. However, when I call `FileDownloader.startDownload()`, `URLSessionDownloadTask` fails (sometimes immediately, sometimes after a few seconds) without an exception. Both `error?.localizedDescription` and `error.debugDescription` are `nil`. This issue doesn't happen if I'm trying to download in the main thread with the code [given in Swift Developer Blog](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/download-file-from-a-remote-url-in-swift/). Is there any way to fix this? Here is how I call the class:

```
let downloader = FileDownloader.init(downloadURL: URL(string: "http://link.to/a/file/on/the/internet")!, identifier: "com.example.myapp.downloader")
downloader.startDownload()
while downloader.downloadStatus == DownloadStatus.InProgress {}
if (downloader.downloadStatus == DownloadStatus.Completed) { /* stuff */ }
else { /* downloadStatus is DownloadStatus.Failed, which is always the case */ }
```

This is a macOS command line tool.

**Edit:** After some testing, it appears that I'm indeed sending a request to the server because `task.response` reveals the following:

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1021037f0> { URL: http://link.to/a/file/on/the/internet } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Accept-Ranges" =     (
    bytes
);
Connection =     (
    "Keep-Alive"
);
"Content-Length" =     (
    9463662
);
....
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your `FileDownloader` class?

Comment: @Chris The first link in the question is a link to the class.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn’t see that that was a link.